# TextController on TextField doesn't listen to changes && OnChanged after being edited once doesn't work anymore

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to be able to edit the TextField and after all of them are filled, a value is calculated. Every time the user change a value, the value must be recalculated.

I've tried with both the Streams and Controller. The stream was doing fine, even tho the update of the value was done with data's that were 1 change old.
i.e. `height`, `weight` and `age` all must be `!= null`, when we have at first `{height: 2, weight:3, age:2}`, it doesn't get calculated, after one of them is changed then the result is calculated but with the above data.
The controller instead doesn't seem to listen on the variable change at all.

Here I initialize the controller in another class

```
class Bsmi extends StatelessWidget {
  StreamController<void> valueBoxStream = StreamController<void>.broadcast();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new DefaultAppBar(context: context, title: Text(" ")),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          BsmiResult(valueBoxStream, {}),
          new Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              itemExtent: 80.0,
              children: <Widget>[
                _BsmiResultState().indices("height", valueBoxStream),
                _BsmiResultState().indices("weight", valueBoxStream),
                _BsmiResultState().indices("age", valueBoxStream),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the important code

```
class BsmiResult extends StatefulWidget {
  final StreamController<void> valueBoxStream;

  const BsmiResult(this.valueBoxStream, this.data);

  final Map data;

  @override
  _BsmiResultState createState() =>
      _BsmiResultState(valueBoxStream: this.valueBoxStream, data: this.data);
}

class _BsmiResultState extends State<BsmiResult> {
  _BsmiResultState({this.valueBoxStream, this.data});
  StreamController<void> valueBoxStream;

  final Map data;

  final textFieldController = new TextEditingController();

  int weight;
  int age;
  int height;
  String _result = "0.0";



  _printLatestValue() {
    print("Second text field: ${textFieldController.text}");
  }

  void setData(data) {
    if (data['type'] == 'height') {
      print("I'm inside height\n");
      height = int.parse(data['value']);
    } else if (data['type'] == 'weight') {
      print("I'm inside weight\n");
      weight = int.parse(data['value']);
    } else {
      print("I'm inside age\n");
      age = int.parse(data['value']);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textFieldController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
    valueBoxStream.stream.listen((_){
      _calculateResult();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the Widget is removed from the Widget tree
    textFieldController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _calculateResult() {
      if ((height != null) && (height != 0) && (weight != null) && (weight != 0) && (age != null) && (age != 0)) {
        print("height: " +
            height.toString() +
            "" +
            " weight: " +
            weight.toString() +
            " age: " +
            age.toString());
        _result = ((height + weight) / age).toString();
        print(_result + "\n");
      } else {
        _result = "0.0";
      }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("Risultato"),
        new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ), //For the controller i don't use the StreamBuilder but a normal Text("$_result"),
          child: StreamBuilder(  
            stream: valueBoxStream.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData || _result !=  "0.0") {
                print(snapshot.data);
                setData(snapshot.data);
                return new Text(
                  "$_result",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                );
              } else {
                return new Text(
                  "0.0",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Row indices(String text, StreamController<void> valueBoxStream) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        leftSection(text),
        rightSection(text, valueBoxStream),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget leftSection(text) {
    return new Expanded(
      child: new Container(
        child: new Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Container rightSection(text, valueBoxStream) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Flexible(
        flex: 1,
        child: new TextField(
          controller: textFieldController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp("[0-9.]")),
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
          ],
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(width: 1.2),
            ),
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
            ),
            hintText: '0.0',
          ),
          onChanged: (val) {
            valueBoxStream.add({'type': text, 'value': val});
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I should be able at this point to get `Result: x.y`, but I get it only once after I change the textField only once and in the same `'session'`

Thanks in advance who can really explain to me why this is not working and what errors I'm making.

Comment: can you please try to reduce your code sample to a simple reproducable example. I couldn't even find where your `indices` method is called.. your code wouldn't even show the text field..

Comment: @herbert sorry i updated now the code. My bad

Comment: sorry, but you are doing something very weird there.. You can't just create a state of a stateful widget, without the stateful widget itself. I have no idea how you imagine that this can work.. the lifecycle of the state is tightly coupled with that of the widget. You can't just use the State of a widget, without the widget itself. This is all weird. I doubt that those states will get initialized correctly. Make sure to use the the StatefulWidget, instead of the State objects directly!

Comment: @herbert So basically you are saying that i have to move kinda everything from the State Widget inside the StatefulWidget?

Comment: I think you have mangled two widgets into one.. you should simply extract `indices`, `leftSection`, `rightSection` into it's own `StatefulWidget` .. I don't quite understand why it's together with the ResultWidget.. as a general rule, I would recommend trying to keep all widgets as small as possible.. you somehow put everything into one widget's state for no good reason imho

Comment: I wanted to make everything modular, because i might reuse something. So i should just create a StatefulWidget for that `indices`?

Comment: yes.. and the smaller your widgets are, the better reusable they are!

Comment: Ok thanks, but still the onChanged once is set, if you lose the focus on the TextField, the onChange doesn't get trigger anymore. Why's that?

Comment: can you share your code? like a repo or github gist which i could easily run?

Comment: @herbert https://pastebin.com/Tuccnwu9 this is everything to reproduce, but i just noticed that it works! While in my app it doesn't... I'm pretty confused lol

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the link to the whole project: https://gitlab.com/Nindo/clinimetric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sorry.. but there have been so many things wrong with that code, I'm not even sure where to begin. It looks like you read all versions on how to handle state in flutter and managed to combine it all in one simple use case.. Here is one working example fix: https://gitlab.com/hpoul/clinimetric/commit/413d32d4041f2e6adb7e30af1126af4b05e72271

I'm not sure how to answer this "question" so that others could possibly benefit from it. but..

1. If you create a stream controller or a text view controller.. You have state.. hence, create a stateful widget (otherwise you can't for example close streams and subscriptions)
2. Get a handle on which widget is responsible for which state. And pass down only useful values to child views. One possible architecture is to use a ViewController and use Sinks as inputs for change events, and Streams for handling those events. So if you create a stream controller, only use a streamController.sink if you want to notify of events, and use a streamController.stream if a widget needs to listen to events
3. the build method is not the right place to handle events. I refactored your code that the handling of events and calculation of events is done in the listener of the stream. If you want to use a StreamBuilder you could have a StreamController and your producers directly push the Result into the sink.. so the builder method of the StreamBuilder would only need to do Text('${snapshot.data.value}')

There are probably quite a few things i'm missing in that list. but that should get you started. look at my change set. It is not perfect, but it works. You should try to understand what you are doing and reduce complexity instead of stacking everything you find on top of each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I didn't know i made so many mistakes, i'll go through each one of them and i'll understand better the why behind everything! You are a lifesaver!

Comment: @Benny you're welcome. If you've tried my fixes and it works for you, please accept the answer. if there is anything you don't understand just let me know, I'll try to get into more details.

Comment: I just tried them, but still gotta go through me. Once i'll do it, i will ask if you'll be available! :) `Thanks`

Comment: Hey @herbert so i ran across the code and i didn't understand some things.
1) Why you used the `StreamSubscription`? I saw that using only the StreamController works fine.
2) How SetData get the data parameter? Where is being passed? How does he know that he has to get the `Map data` and update it? Does listen handle the passage of parameters to the function given?
3) So basically `Stream` is for handling event coming and `Sink` is to notify a new event? Thanks